# Moving Files Slow Even With SSD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, performance, ssd

I 'upgraded' to a Samsung 840 Evo SSD drive, and whilst moving some files around on my drive, its slowed to a crawl. Heres a video example:

http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c26DiTej3e

My machine is an i5-3230M CPU @ 2.6Ghz, with 8GB of ram and windows 8.1 64bit.

Surely this should be a lot quicker than this?

Comment: there is Perf fix available for the 840 EVO, make sure it is installed: http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/samsungssd/downloads.html

Comment: have you tried the new firmware? Is the performance better?

Comment: I checked as I have the samsung magician util installed, and it was already at latest version.

Comment: don't run magician, use the **Samsung SSD 840 EVO Performance Restoration Software**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to copy multiple files at once, which makes the operation slower, think about if, if you need to move your stuff from a room to another, is't faster if you have them packed, or to move them one by one ?
Same thing on Windows, 
If you're copying multiple files at once, no matter how the speed you computer is, it'll be slower than your computer are, that's because Windows  cannot move your files as one package, it'll move them one by one, and that takes a longer time than copying one file with same size.

So, if you want to a better copying performance, you should use some other third party tools, or just pack the files into one compressed file, then move that file, it'll move it faster.

Answer (score 1):

Even with an SSD an operation moving hundreds of thousands of files will still be a bit slow, albeit faster then a regular HD, as the OS still has to read meta data, buffer etc... if it was slow moving a single file then I would be worried.

The slow down would be especially true if you are moving from a regular HD to the SSD, as seek times inflate IO wait times